# Why does the concatenation order change with a User-Defined Table Type?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, concat

I've encountered what seems to me to be a strange ordering issue when using `CONCAT` with a User Defined Table Type.

I've put the SQL below that allows me to reproduce this:

I have the following user type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[StringList] AS TABLE
(
    [Value] VARCHAR(8000) NOT NULL
)
```

And the following query to set everything up:

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames AS TABLE([ColumnName] VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @ValueTable AS [dbo].[StringList] --VariableLineA
--DECLARE @ValueTable AS TABLE([Value] VARCHAR(MAX)) --VariableLineB

INSERT INTO @ColumnNames([ColumnName])
VALUES
('Forename'),
('Surname')

INSERT INTO @ValueTable([Value])
VALUES
('Ellis'), ('Ali')
```

And this is the query I'm running:

```
SELECT CONCAT(STRING_AGG(CONCAT([ColumnName], ' - ',  [sc].[Value]), ', '), ', ') -- QueryLineA
        --CONCAT(STRING_AGG([ColumnName] + ' - ' + [sc].[Value], ', '), ', ') --QueryLineB
FROM        @ValueTable AS [sc]
INNER JOIN  @ColumnNames ON 1=1
```

If the `VariableLineB` line is uncommented, and the `VariableLineA` line is commented out, the following string is returned for both query lines if run individually or together:

`Forename - Ellis, Forename - Ali, Surname - Ellis, Surname - Ali,`

If the `VariableLineA` line is uncommented and the `VariableLineB` line is commented out, the following string is returned for `QueryLineB`, and from *both* queries if run together, but *not* `QueryLineA` on its own:

`Forename - Ellis, Forename - Ali, Surname - Ellis, Surname - Ali,`

When `QueryLineA` is run on its own, the following string is returned:

`Forename - Ellis, Surname - Ellis, Forename - Ali, Surname - Ali,`

Why has the order changed?  What am I seeing here, and is there any way to prevent this from happening?

In terms of usage, the values of `@ValueTable` would be getting passed into a function, and it's important that the original order (whatever that may be) remains the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The order changes because the order of the tables involved in the cross join has changed. In one plan `@ValueTable` is the outer (driving) table, in the other `@ColumnNames` is the outer table.

```
for each row in @ColumnNames
    for each row in @ValueTable
    concatenate the result
    //produces Forename - Ellis, Forename - Ali, Surname - Ellis, Surname - Ali, 


for each row in @ValueTable
    for each row in @ColumnNames
    concatenate the result 
    //produces "Forename - Ellis, Surname - Ellis, Forename - Ali, Surname - Ali,"
```

Order is never guaranteed unless specified in the query, so if consistent order is important you should add a stable order by clause defining order for *both* tables inside the `STRING_AGG` definition.

```
SELECT CONCAT(STRING_AGG(CONCAT([ColumnName], ' - ',  [sc].[Value]), ', ') 
                        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [ColumnName],  [sc].[Value])  , ', ') -- QueryLineA
FROM        @ValueTable AS [sc]
INNER JOIN  @ColumnNames ON 1=1
```

Comment: Very informative, thanks!  This may be a dumb question, but does this apply to every result without an `ORDER BY` clause?  I was aware that results are 'unordered' when querying from normal tables, but I guess I somewhat naively didn't realise this could also apply to the likes of `STRING_SPLIT` (and potententially everything else)?

Comment: yes, this is always the case. The [documentation for string split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) explicitly warns `The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string` but unfortunately they don't provide any alternative output column in the result of the function indicating the order so this is often ignored.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, the order of the returned rows is not guaranteed unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause in your query, since a table is *by definition* an unordered set of rows. Thus, the results you add to another table (or table variable) won't have a specific row order unless you give it one when you do a select.

Since you need @ValueTable to have a specified order, you will need to add a sequence to the table - an `IDENTITY` column will work - and `ORDER BY` in your joined query, something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[StringList] AS TABLE
(
    [Order] Int Identity(1,1) not null,
    [Value] VARCHAR(8000) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 2):

[STRING_AGG() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) may contain optional ordering `WITHIN GROUP` clause which specifies the ordering of separate values in aggregated result.

When ordering clause is NOT specified then the values ordering in aggregated value is NOT specified. It is RANDOM and non-deterministic (it may differ from query execution to the next one).

In most cases it is defined by what object was scanned for to extract separate values for concatenation - table scan, index (clustered or non-) scan, temporary table/index, extracting by referenced field value while extracting values from another fields of joined table using this another table scan by some way, etc...

Query plan change or/and any another factor may change extracting order (even when the plan stays unchanged!), and this cause that the aggregation order may change too.

Remember - "no values ordering clause specified or documented" is equal to "the ordering may be any" in all cases.